# My device doesnt recognize my DB where my emulator does

Tags: android

When I try to query using my db in the femulator it works perfectly, but given the same appliction and same varibales into the device (milestone) it seems like the DB is not recognized.

I think the key to solving it is to understand where on the device we store the db.
On the emulator it's on `/data/data/com.countryCityGame/databases/test1.db`

But when I am using the device itself it must be in another place, does someone know where?

This is the java code where I build the DB:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String CITIES[] = city.split(",");
    String ANIMEL[] = animel.split(",");
    String CELEB[] = UK_CELEB.split(","); 
    String Nature[] = vegtablesAndFruiets.split(","); 
    String V[][] = {COUNTRIES,CITIES,ANIMEL,Nature,occupations,CELEB}; 
    String []TypeNames = {"Country","City","Animels","Nature","Occupation","Celeb"};

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test1.db");

    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    //stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists "+"android_metadata"+";");
    stat.executeUpdate("create table android_metadata (\"locale\" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');");
    //PreparedStatement prep1 = conn.prepareStatement(
           //   "insert into "+"android_metadata"+" values (?);");

    //prep1.setString(1, "en_US") ;
    //prep1.addBatch(); 

    stat.executeUpdate("drop table if exists "+TABLE_NAME+";");
    //stat.executeUpdate("create table "+TABLE_NAME+" (name, occupation);");
    stat.executeUpdate("create table "+TABLE_NAME+" ("+VALUE+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+TYPE+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+LETTER+" TEXT NOT NULL,"+counter+" INTEGER);");
    PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(
      "insert into "+TABLE_NAME+" values (?,?,?,?);");

    //private void insertToTalble();
    int j=0,i=0;
    try{
        for(j = 0 ;j < V.length; j++)
            for (i = 0 ;i < V[j].length ; i++)
            {
            if  (V[j][i] != null)
            {
                V[j][i] = asUpperCaseFirstChar(V[j][i]);
                Character c = V[j][i].charAt(0);
                prep.setString(3, c.toString());
            }

            prep.setString(1, V[j][i]);
            prep.setString(2, TypeNames[j]);
            prep.setInt(4,0);

            prep.addBatch();
            }
    }catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("***********"+i+"***************");          
    }

    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    prep.executeBatch();
   // prep1.executeBatch();
    conn.setAutoCommit(true);
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME+";");

    while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println("country name = " + rs.getString(VALUE));
      System.out.println("type = " + rs.getString(TYPE));
      System.out.println("letter = " + rs.getString(LETTER));
      System.out.println("********************************");
    }
    rs.close();
    conn.close();
  }
```

**and this is the code from where i first get the bug:**

```
private static final String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.countryCityGame/databases/test1.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "test1.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "GameTable";
    private static final String VALUE = "value";
    private static final String TYPE = "type";
    private static final String LETTER = "letter";


    public countryCityGameLogic(EditText[] myEditTextArr , Context context) {

        points = 0;//init values
        Cursor cursor = null ;
        this.context = context;
        openHelper = new OpenHelper(context);
        gameList = new CharSequence [myEditTextArr.length];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < myEditTextArr.length; i++){
            gameList[i] = myEditTextArr[i].getText();
        }
        //this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        try{
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH , null,  SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS/*SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY*/);
            //this question 
            cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {LETTER}
            ,LETTER+ " like " + "'%" + "A" +"%'", null, null, null, null);  
            if ( !cursor.moveToFirst()){
                //*****if data base doesnot exist HERE I GOT PROBLEMES****
                this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();//make new data base

                }
        }catch(SQLiteException e){

            this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();//make new data base
        //  for (int i = 0 ; i < ALLVALUES.length ; i++) 
        //          insertValus(ALLVALUES[i],i);


        }
```

**NOTICE:** In the device I am using `/data/data/com.countryCityGame/databases/test1.db`, it might not be the path where the appliction is located onto the device I am using.

Comment: Can you add some more information? Code examples? How do you create the database? Where is it stored? etc.

Comment: I hope it's answer your need for farther information 
i also think Notice is the key for understanding it ...

Comment: Well it sounds like your SQLiteOpenHelper isn't creating the database properly.  That's the code you should post.
Also, I'm not sure why you're using JDBC.

Comment: i want to write the DB outside the android therefore i used jdbc 'yes it's possible to do it onto the device but not the best practice .